# How to auto update text on widget in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

In app.kv file there is a button:

```
Button:
    text: var1
```

Sometimes var1 changes. How to change text on button (or label, etc) without an explicit attribute assignments in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kivy can do that automatically for you - but only if var1 is a kivy-property. You can read more about them [here](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/events.html#introduction-to-properties)

If that doesn't happen already that means that var1 is not a kivy property. You must set them as class attributes, e.g.:

```
class MyWidget
    var1 = NumericProperty()
    [...]
```

and then in kv:

```
MyWidget:
    Button:
        text: root.var1
```

or whatever you want. As long as the value you are setting it to is a kivy property, it should work. Sometimes if the value on the right side is a complicated one (`text: "" if root.var is None else getattr("mystring", root.var)`) things don't work out easily, but if you run in that case there are other stackoverflow questions which should help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the property directly of course. No need to do `text: var1`. These are quite common ways, but except them there's even [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) or some others.

**Through its instance:**

```
<Buttons_Root>:
    Button:
        id: mybutton
```

→ py:

```
b = Buttons_Root()
b.ids.mybutton.text = 'something'
```

**Through its parent:**

```
<MyBoxLayout>:
    Button:
```

→ py:

```
box = MyBoxLayout()
box.children[0].text = 'something'
```